# Indian father, Bangladeshi mother, a baby expect to be born in Ireland

Tags: citizenship, ireland, passport

This is my first post in this community.

I am an ordinary Indian passport holder, I am in Dublin, doing full-time Ph.D. studies since October 2018 on a stamp 2 student visa. http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/inis/pages/registration-stamps

My wife joined me in Dublin last year January, as an immediate dependent family-member with me and she has given me a stamp 2A visa. She holds a Bangladeshi passport.

A baby is expected to be born in September in Dublin. What passport we should apply for, for the baby? Indian/Bangladeshi/Irish?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to consult with an immigration attorney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your child probably does not qualify for Irish [birth citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_nationality_law#Acquisition_of_citizenship) since residence of the parent on a student visa does not count.
- Your child probably does qualify for Indian citizenship since you are Indian and/or for Bangladeshi citizenship since the mother is Bangladeshi. Applying for both would make the child a dual citizen, which appears to be discouraged by Indian law.

Citizenship is such a serious matter that it might be a good idea to consult a lawyer. Before you do that, you could ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange so you know the right questions to ask.

Comment: I concur with seeing a specialist lawyer. India laws in general, and citizenship / nationality ones in particular, a *really* complicated. (Don't know why this was down voted though?)

Comment: @RockApe, it might have been a hint to me that I should have voted to close instead of answering.